# Create and save a GSheet file with list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

Have dict1 {subdict1,subdict2}, dict2 {subdict1,subdict2} and dict3 (doesnt have subdicts) into a list 'insights', need to create a gsheet file for each dict of 'insights' list but a sheet for each subdict, this is what its inside 'insights':

```
[{'city': {'name': 'follower_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Follower demographics',
   'type': 'city',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of followers, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''},
  'gender': {'name': 'follower_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Follower demographics',
   'type': 'gender',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of followers, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''},
  'country': {'name': 'follower_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Follower demographics',
   'type': 'country',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of followers, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''},
  'age': {'name': 'follower_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Follower demographics',
   'type': 'age',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of followers, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''}},
 {'city': {'name': 'reached_audience_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Reached audience demographics',
   'type': 'city',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of the reached audience, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''},
  'gender': {'name': 'reached_audience_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Reached audience demographics',
   'type': 'gender',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of the reached audience, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''},
  'country': {'name': 'reached_audience_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Reached audience demographics',
   'type': 'country',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of the reached audience, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''},
  'age': {'name': 'reached_audience_demographics',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Reached audience demographics',
   'type': 'age',
   'description': 'The demographic characteristics of the reached audience, including countries, cities and gender distribution.',
   'df': ''}},
 {'name': 'follower_count',
  'period': 'day',
  'title': 'Follower Count',
  'description': 'Total number of unique accounts following this profile',
  'df': ''}]
```

As you can see in summary the list is the following:

```
insights = [
    follower_demographics,
    reached_demographics,
    followers_count
]
```

And this is what each dictionary of the list have, in the case of **'follower_demographics'** it breaks in a dictionary of ['city', 'gender', 'country', 'age'] where inside each one is this:

```
demographics = {
        'name': '',
        'period': '',
        'title': '',
        'type': '',
        'description': '',
        'df': ''
    }
```

So I did the function below to create a file for the 3 dictionaries of **'insights'**, the problem is that it creates 4 files of **'follower_demographics'** and each one with one respective dataframe.

```
def create_gsheet(insights, folder_id):
    try:
        # create a list to store the created files
        files = []

        # iterate over the items in the insights dictionary
        for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(insights.items()):
            # check if the value is a dictionary
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                # Create a new file with the name taken from the 'title' key
                file = gc.create(value['title'], folder=folder_id)

                print(f"Creating {value['title']} - {idx}/{len(insights)}")

                # add the file to the list
                files.append(file)

                
                # Create a new sheet within the file with the name taken from the 'name' key
                sheet = file.add_worksheet(value['type'] + '_' + value['name'])

                # Set the sheet data to the df provided in the dictionary
                sheet.set_dataframe(value['df'], (1,1), encoding='utf-8', fit=True)

                sheet.frozen_rows = 1


        # delete the default sheet1 from all the created files
        for file in files:
            file.del_worksheet(file.sheet1)

    except Exception as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        sheet = None
```

And the result I want is that for example create **'follower_demographics'** file and as *sub_sheets* **'city_follower_demographics'**, **'gender_follower_demographics'** with their respective dataframes.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `this is what its inside 'insights':`, `insights = [,,,]` and `demographics = {,,,}`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yeah sure, don't worry. The thing is that I have a list(dict{subdict{}}).

list = insights
dict = follower_demographics
breakdowns = ['city', 'gender', 'country', 'age']
city (for example) = demographics

Please let me know if this is cleared. Thank you (tell me your language too)